# Типы и функции наречий

Tags: морфология, части-речи, наречия

**Как никогда** и **остро** какие наречия - качественные или количественные.И какая их роль предложения (обстоятельства чего?)

> В эти минуты, **как никогда**, **остро** чувствуешь...

Я думаю так:

1)Как никогда - в значении очень -значит наречие степени (то есть количественное). Неместоименное. Обстоятельство степени

2)Остро - как? - есть степени сравнения - значит качественное.Неместоименное. Обстоятельство образа действия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*В эти минуты (**в какие** минуты?), **как никогда (= как ни  в какие другие)**...*

===

Здесь ***как никогда́*** --  несогласованное определение, выраженное  *нареч. качеств.-обстоят.*
(http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/172825/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA )

===

***остро*** чувствуешь...

> Остро - как? - есть степени сравнения - значит качественное.

Да.

> Обстоятельство образа действия?

Да, *образа действия.* Иногда эти обстоятельства называют *определительно-качественными,* иногда -- *качественными.*

Answer (score 0):

У вас очень странная пунктуация. 
Можно выбирать между "В эти минуты, как никогда остро, чувствуешь..." и "В эти минуты как никогда остро чувствуешь...", но запятая между "никогда" и "остро" сильно меняет грамматику - а через неё и функцию наречий. 
В остальном согласен Вами, при вашем разборе я бы вообще без запятых писал.

Comment: Так если бы было без запятых, и я бы был согласен. А с запятыми...

Comment: Ну вообще-то я исходил из её разбора. Так что пунктуация должна следовать за смыслом, а не наоборот.

Comment: Но в задании-то запятые есть. См. https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%92+%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%2C+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%2C+%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE+%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%D0%92+%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B,+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0,+%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE+%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C&tbm=bks

Comment: Ах вон оно что... Ну тогда я, пожалуй, соглашусь с Вами...